# Servlet is not invoking when called from jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am unable to invoke my servlet please help me out. Below is my code.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action= "/RoleCommand.do" method = "post">
name:<input type ="text" name = "name"/><br></br>
id:<input type = "text" name= "id"/><br></br>
<input type = "submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>


Servlet code


public class RoleCommand extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public RoleCommand() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PrintWriter p = response.getWriter();
        p.println("hi");
        response.sendRedirect("ValidServlet");
String name = request.getParameter("name");
String id = request.getParameter("id");
}
}
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Form</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Controller</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.controller.Controller</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Controller</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>DatabaseCon</display-name>
    <servlet-name>DatabaseCon</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.database.DatabaseCon</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DatabaseCon</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/DatabaseCon</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Transaction</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Transaction</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.database.Transaction</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Transaction</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Transaction</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>RoleCommand</display-name>
    <servlet-name>RoleCommand</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.command.RoleCommand</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RoleCommand</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/RoleCommand</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

As per the above code it should print on to the console once executed. But when i am clicking on submit button it's throwing an exception resource not found.

Please help me .

Comment: y did u put ROleCOmmand.do?

Comment: Use Firebug or Chrome developer tool or Fiddler to see network passage of URL to make sure Servlet in indeed getting invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Remove .do from action and action class should be like following  action= **"/RoleCommand"**

Answer (score 0):

you have wrong mapping of the servlet.
in web.xml

```
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>RoleCommand</display-name>
    <servlet-name>RoleCommand</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.command.RoleCommand</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RoleCommand</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/RoleCommand</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

change url-pattern to *.do or /RoleCommand.do.
or you can change your form action

```
<form action= "/RoleCommand.do" method = "post">
```

to

```
<form action= "/RoleCommand" method = "post">
```

Note: both form action and url-pattern must match in order to invoke a servlet from jsp.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `form` as follows, that may help you

```
<form action="http://localhost:8080/packagename/serveltclassname" >
```